# magento unable to load the observe class

Tags: events, magento, observers

when i try to write the observer for the `checkout_type_onepage_save_order` event like following

```
<events>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
        <observers>
            <Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>consignor/observer</class>
                <method>savedata</method>
            </Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
</events>
```

above code i tried in `frontend` as well as `global`.

Even i tried following as well.

```
<events>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
        <observers>
            <Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>savedata</method>
            </Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
</events>
```

full config.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Appeal_Consignor>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Appeal_Consignor>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <consignor>
                <class>Appeal_Consignor_Model</class>
            </consignor>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <consignor_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Appeal_Consignor</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </consignor_setup>
            <consignor_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </consignor_write>
            <consignor_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </consignor_read>
        </resources>
        <helpers>
            <consignor>
                <class>Appeal_Consignor_Helper</class>
            </consignor>
        </helpers>
    </global>


    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <consignor>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Appeal_Consignor</module>
                    <frontName>consignor</frontName>
                </args>
            </consignor>
        </routers>


        <events>
            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
                <observers>
                    <Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>savedata</method>
                    </Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>

        </events>


    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <consignor>
                    <file>consignor.xml</file>
                </consignor>
            </updates>
        </layout>


    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

yet the following error is coming. I cleared cache 1000 times, deleted var cache folder file manually as well.

```
2012-07-23T11:04:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2012-07-23T11:04:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\includes\src;.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR')  in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
```

Comment: you should write in this way `<class>consignor/observer</class>` for magento < 2.0. Also you may remove `<connection>`, `<consignor_write>` and `<consignor_read>` nodes. Then in your `.htaccess` file set env var `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1`. After that provide us with coming results

Comment: please also post your model file. I am sure you must have checked it many times, may be the class name is not matching that of in config.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I am using to run the observer when a new product is added to the cart:

etc\config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Iln_Cartvalidation>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Iln_Cartvalidation>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <helpers>
                <cartvalidation>
                    <class>Iln_Cartvalidation_Helper</class>
                </cartvalidation>
            </helpers>
        </global>
        <frontend>
            <events>
                <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                    <observers>
                        <Iln_Cartvalidation_Model_Observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Iln_Cartvalidation_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>Mytestmethod</method>
                        </Iln_Cartvalidation_Model_Observer>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            </events>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

Helper\Data.php

```
    <?php
    class Iln_Cartvalidation_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    }
```

Model\observer.php

```
<?php
class Iln_Cartvalidation_Model_Observer {

    public function Mytestmethod($observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent(); //Fetches the current event
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $eventmsg = "Current Event Triggered : " . $event->getName() . "Currently Added Product : " . $product->getName();
        //Adds Custom message to shopping cart
        echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($eventmsg);
        //Your Custom Logic Here
        print_r($product);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Judging by the include warning, it seems like you have the compiler enabled but it cannot find the (flattened) file.

So either disable the compiler:

```
php shell/compiler.php disable
```

Or run a compilation so that it will generate the file for you:

```
php shell/compiler.php compile
```

Comment: This.  Look at the **file** name in include. include(Appeal_Consignor_Model_Observer.php).  Whenever you see a fully_underscored_file_name that means Magento is looking for a file in the compiled folder.

Comment: Exactly what @AlanStorm said. Another thing that gives it away is the include path (includes\src).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should helps to you:

```
<events>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
        <observers>
            <consignor>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>consignor/observer</class>
                <method>savedata</method>
            </consignor>
        </observers>
    </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
</events>
```