# Magento module extension Model Resource Setup not found

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to install the Magento Clever CMS module https://github.com/jreinke/magento-clever-cms on a Magento 1.7.0.2 install.

On my development environment I can install it without any problems, but on production I get an internal server error.

PHP Fatal error:

> Class 'JR_CleverCms_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in /web/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234

So the Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup is not extended with the JR_CleverCms resource setup. 
I've installed the module with modgit and double checked if all files are there and permissions of the files. Anyone got an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to compilation being enabled on your production environment, but that file has not been 'compiled' (copied to includes/src).

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611433/magento-unable-to-load-the-observe-class/11611769#11611769) for a solution.

Comment: Thanks, disabling compilation fixed the issue