# Magento observer doesn't seem to be catching events

Tags: magento

I've followed a tutorial, but my observer isn't catching events.  I know the events are firing because I'm logging them.  I can't find the error in my code.

/local/Package/MODULE/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Package_MODULE>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Package_MODULE>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <module>
            <class>Package_MODULE_Model</class>
        </module>
    </models>
    <events>
            <catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after>
                    <observers>
                            <module_model_upload>
                                    <type>model</type>
                                    <class>module/observer</class>
                                    <method>printTestMessage</method>
                            </module_model_upload>
                    </observers>
            </catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after>
    </events>

</global>
</config>
```

/local/Package/MODULE/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Package_MODULE_Model_Observer{
    public function printTestMessage(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
             Mage::log("TESTING ", null, 'events.log');  //<--same log statement I'm using to test the events firing
    }
}
```

/etc/modules/Package_MODULE.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Package_MODULE>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Package_MODULE>
</modules>
</config>
```

EDIT2:  This error shows up in system.log:

```
2013-02-14T17:10:21+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/includes/src/Varien_File_Uploader.php on line 538
2013-02-14T17:10:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/includes/src/Package_MODULE_Model_Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2013-02-14T17:10:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/includes/src/Package_MODULE_Model_Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/includes/src:.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php')  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
```

Comment: The model definition in XML should only contain module name, and not module_model.. `<module>` instead of `<module_model>`

Comment: @KalpeshMehta I made the change.  Still nothing happens.

Comment: Some stupid question, but :
- are you sure log is enabled ?
- does the events.log files exists with writeable permission ? if No is the log directory writable to allow new file creation ?
- have you tried simply Mage::log('test'); ?

Comment: @dagfr Yes the logging is working.  I have noticed something in system.log.  I'll post it in the question.

Comment: Ok, we notice 2 things in your error log. 1 compilation is enabled, did you recompile your code ? 2. you see the error described by @KalpeshMetha 2 times Model

Comment: Yep.  I made that change already though.  I'll try deleting my cache.

Comment: I deleted my cache, and now I get the same error, but with only one "_model" in it.   I put the new error in the question under EDIT2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the include warning... This is due to the compiler being enabled but your class hasn't been compiled.

I've answered this question probably more times than I can count: [disable the compiler or recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611433/magento-unable-to-load-the-observe-class/11611769#11611769).

Comment: Thank you!    Question about the compiler:  Do I need it enabled for when the site goes live?

Comment: @swl1020: You don't -need- to, but it could be beneficial for performance reasons (especially when mounting includes/src as tmpfs).

Comment: I see.  So,  while in development, it's best to disable,  then when launch day comes,  re-enable and recompile?

Comment: yes exactly, don't compile while you make daily change. Compile once stable.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong class name in the configuration for your observer. `<class>module_model/observer</class>` doesn't want the _model in it. The class alias for the model `Package_MODULE_Model_Observer` is `module/observer`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  That error isn't actually in my code.   I made a change to my code, then came here to reflect the change, but forgot to update that section.   Thanks though!