# Getting Error in includes folder in system.log

Tags: magento, controller, magento-1.7, simplexml

In system.log folder , I am getting error

```
includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action.php' ....
includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93


function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: &lt;/config--&gt; ....
includes/src/__default.php on line 31919
```

It started occuring suddenly .
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following error can occur because of compilation .

[You can refer here .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879236/magento-observer-doesnt-seem-to-be-catching-events)

In magento there are thousands of class navigation .
To reduce class navigation process , Magento smartly wraps (or caches) all class navigation under `includes/src` folder structure , when we turn on compilation .

After turning on compilation if we add new modules or code which deals with class extend part , its entry is not added in `includes/src` , and so the error may be thrown .

To overcome this , there are some ways to bring it back to line :

1.) If new modules are added , `Disable compilation` , `delete cache` , `Run compilation` (go_to_admin->System->Tools->Compilation)

2.) If the module has backend management ,Please check `way_to_your_module/controllers/Adminhtml/(Your_controller)Controller.php`

here the extended controller should me `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` (**Action** should be in capital letter)

After this repeat Step 1 .

Thanks . Hope it helps .

***NOTE*** : It is wise to Enable compilation after developing work .