# Magento event not firing

Tags: magento

I'm trying to fire an observer when a product is added to the shopping cart, here is my code:

*app/etc/modules/Mydons_Eventdemo.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mydons_Eventdemo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mydons_Eventdemo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Mydons/Eventdemo/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mydons_Eventdemo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mydons_Eventdemo>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>Mytestmethod</method>
                    </Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and *app/code/local/Mydons/Eventdemo/Model/Observer.php*

```
<?php

class Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer {
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'hello world';
        die();
    }
    public function Mytestmethod($observer) {

        $event = $observer->getEvent();  //Fetches the current event
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $eventmsg = "Current Event Triggered : <I>" . $event->getName() . "</I><br/> Currently Added Product : <I> " . $product->getName()."</I>";
        //Adds Custom message to shopping cart
        echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($eventmsg);
        //Your Custom Logic Here
        //you can use print_r($product) here to get more details
    }

}
```

But when I add a product to the shopping cart, it just ran like it usually does. Is there anything wrong here? Please help!

Update: I checked the log file: system.log and got these:

```
2014-05-27T07:17:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 22: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 21  in D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\__default.php on line 22352
2014-05-27T07:17:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:   in D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\__default.php on line 22352
2014-05-27T07:17:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: ^  in D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\__default.php on line 22352
2014-05-27T07:17:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 22: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 2  in D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\__default.php on line 22352
2014-05-27T07:17:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:   in D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\__default.php on line 22352
2014-05-27T07:17:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: ^  in D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\__default.php on line 22352
```

But I have no idea what it is.

Update2: I run it again and get a more clearly log message:

```
2014-05-27T07:29:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2014-05-27T07:29:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src;.;D:\Webserver\php\PEAR')  in D:\Webserver\htdocs\magento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
```

Comment: Are your paths to the files correct `app/code/Mydons/Eventdemo/etc/config.xml` is incorrect it should be `app/code/local/Mydons/Eventdemo/etc/config.xml`

Comment: I'm sorry it was a typo error, the path is app/code/local/Mydons/Eventdemo/etc/config.xml, I editted my question.

Comment: Try compiling the code again. and the flush cache and check

Comment: Still the same result and log message, and cache is not enabled in my magento.

Comment: See the same is mentioned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611433/magento-unable-to-load-the-observe-class

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just compile it and now it worked! I can't believe I wasted my whole morning and almost reinstall magento because of this. Thank you Dushyant Joshi, for being really patient with me. Please make you comment an answer so I can accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: @user1985916, it happens sometimes, one can ognore a silly mistake :). Happy that your problem is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described in  question "the include warning" , it seems like you have the compiler enabled but it cannot find the  proper file i.e. `Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer.php`.

Try recompiling the code again. Flush the cache, if enabled, then check if it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

You have `die()` in constructor so when magento creates the class the script is stopped and the method is not called at all.

Comment: If so it must return a blank page or have "hello world" at least, but it just run like it usually does :(

Comment: You are right. I am testing this on one of my magento projects and your code is working fine. Double check magento cache and server (apc, memcache). Try to restart the server. If it won't help check if some other extension does not stops the script before your observer is fired.

Comment: I tried to restart the server, then remove all other extensions (there is only a helloworld module though), but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with below one

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mydons_Eventdemo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mydons_Eventdemo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>Mytestmethod</method>
                    </Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
    </global>
<config>
```

Comment: @user1985916, your above mentioned code(in your question) is already working fine. did you check with Mage::log();

Comment: @Ankita, does that make any difference by using <global> instead of <frontend> ? I believe both should work

Comment: I checked the log file and updated my question, please read the question again.

Comment: @user1985916, this is because something is wrong with your config.xml or any other configuration files so the parsing error

Comment: @DushyantJoshi I update my question again. Is this because there is something wrong with my magento configuration?

Comment: @user1985916, you first update suggested that. but check my comment above in the question